# Ubuntu software store not working

Tags: python, playonlinux

i try to install or un-install some think and i get this:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 222127 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing vlc ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for vlc-nox ...
dpkg: error processing python-wxgtk2.8 (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of playonlinux:
 playonlinux depends on python-wxgtk2.8; however:
  Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: error processing playonlinux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-wxgtk2.8
 playonlinux
Error in function: 
dpkg: error processing python-wxgtk2.8 (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of playonlinux:
 playonlinux depends on python-wxgtk2.8; however:
  Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing playonlinux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: @Jobin it's not a dupe of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below commands on terminal to reinstall the above mentioned packages,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-wxgtk2.8
sudo apt-get install --reinstall playonlinux
```

Because the error report clearly says,

```
Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

Comment: is this works? Maybe some files were missing.